# Convert to scientific notation, Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, scientific-notation

```
print "= ", W_ / 1000, "m^3/min"
```

Currently this shows up as `0.001 m^3/min`
How do I make it display as `1.000e-03 m^3/min`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings), which gives you all the control you need over the formatting of floating point values:

```
print '= {:.3e} m^3/min'.format(W_ / 1000)
```

The `.3` is the precision (3 decimal digits), the `e` tells the floating point object to use scientific notation.

Note that I only needed to create *one string*, and the `{..}` form a placeholder where the first argument passed to the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is inserted.

Demo:

```
>>> W_ = 1.0
>>> print '= {:.3e} m^3/min'.format(W_ / 1000)
= 1.000e-03 m^3/min
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `print("{:.3e}".format(W))`

useful link
https://mkaz.com/2012/10/10/python-string-format/